# Is it bad practice to include classes within classes?

Tags: php, oop, class

Let's say I have a class file called smallBox.php:

```
<?php
class SmallBox {

    public function boxMethod() {}

}
```

I then include the smallBox.php file into another class using 'require':

```
<?php
class BigBox {

    public function __construct() {

        require 'smallBox.php';
        $box = new SmallBox();
        $box->boxMethod();

    }

}
?>
```

I am new to PHP OOP and MVC and was wondering if including smallBox.php in the BigBox class is considered bad practice?

Comment: You might get a better answer over at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: bad\good its all situational.

Comment: try [autoloading](http://phpmaster.com/autoloading-and-the-psr-0-standard) instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of manually `require`-ing PHP files, you should use [autoloading of classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php). Basically, it's a mechanism of loading appropriate PHP files based on a class name.

Answer (score 2):

Use required_once and include_once. Use include structure before class declaration

```
include_once 'path/to/class/a.php';

class B extends A
{
  public function __construct()
  {
     // your code
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

That will work, but remember when you include or require other files, those files variables will operate within the scope of where it's included. I once tried to emulate javas import behavior with a "loader" class, but ran into this issue as the classes I was loading weren't available outside of that main class' scope. Check the manual for more clarity.